# Joomla! 3.6.5 Unknown column 'c.version' in 'field list'

Tags: joomla

I was given the a copy of the folder "httpdocs" and a .sql of the Joomla database from a fully operational site on plesk, and was asked to mount the website locally.

The version of Joomla is 3.6.5, I checked it on the en-GB.xml. The PHP version on the original server was 5.4.45, and now I am using Xampp 1.8.2 with PHP 5.4.31.

After changing the configuration.php to connect to the database, and then accessing the site I get this error:

> 1054 - Unknown column '`c.version`' in 'field list'
>
> SQL=
>
> ```
> SELECT c.id, c.asset_id, c.access, c.alias, c.checked_out, c.checked_out_time,
>        c.created_time, c.created_user_id, c.description, c.extension,
>        c.hits, c.language, c.level, c.lft, c.metadata, c.metadesc,
>        c.metakey, c.modified_time, c.note, c.params, c.parent_id,
>        c.path, c.published, c.rgt, c.title, c.modified_user_id, c.version,
>        CASE
>            WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) != 0 THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias)
>            ELSE c.id
>        END as slug,
>        COUNT(i.`id`) AS numitems
> FROM #__categories as c
> LEFT JOIN (
>     SELECT cat.id as id
>     FROM #__categories AS cat
>     JOIN #__categories AS parent ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
>     WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content'
>         AND parent.published != 1 GROUP BY cat.id
> ) AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id
> LEFT JOIN #__categories AS s ON 
>     (s.lft < c.lft AND s.rgt > c.rgt AND c.language in ('en-GB','*'))
>      OR (s.lft >= c.lft AND s.rgt <= c.rgt)
> LEFT JOIN `#__content` AS i ON
>      i.`catid` = c.id AND i.state = 1 AND (i.language = '*' OR i.language = 'en-GB')
> WHERE (c.extension='com_content' OR c.extension='system')
>     AND c.access IN (1,1)
>     AND c.published = 1
>     AND badcats.id is null
>     AND s.id=10
> GROUP BY c.id, c.asset_id, c.access, c.alias, c.checked_out,
>     c.checked_out_time, c.created_time, c.created_user_id,
>     c.description, c.extension, c.hits, c.language, c.level,
>     c.lft, c.metadata, c.metadesc, c.metakey, c.modified_time,
>     c.note, c.params, c.parent_id, c.path, c.published, c.rgt,
>     c.title, c.modified_user_id, c.version
> ORDER BY c.lft
> ```

From what I have seen, this error is common in websites that are being updated from Joomla! 2.5 to 3.x, this one is not.

I am not very familiar with Joomla!, but I will update this question with any requested information.

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask all of your Joomla question there.

Comment: Cross-posted and educationally answered @ https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/29052/12352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently I was given a database for Joomla! 2.5 instead of the current version, now it works fine